# Recompiling Jar Dependencies

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

Let's say I have a project with a dependency on a class in JAR A, which subsequently has a dependency on a class in JAR B.  To run the project, both jars need to be on the same class path.  I have the source code for all three pieces - project, JAR A, and JAR B.

If I change the internals of the method in the class in JAR B without changing the API, do I need to recompile JAR A against it, or can I just drop it into the classpath of the project and go?

If I think about it, I don't think I would need to but I just want to double check.  It's quite annoying copying the files around all the time when I'm just trying to add extra logging to JAR B which has no effect on JAR A.

Comment: sounds pretty simple to test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code which populates Jar A only needs to be able to compile in order to create the jar.

If it relies on Jar B to compile, then Jar B needs to exist to the extent that it satisfies all of the references made to it by the code for Jar A.

The opposite is also true.

Once the code for Jar A has compiled, you can create it's jar and forget about it.

You can then change Jar B as much as you like as long as the API Jar A uses doesn't change.

EG:

In Jar B you define a function:

```
public class JarBClass
{
    public static void doSomething()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

This compiles and you can create Jar B.

In Jar A you reference the function:

```
public class JarAClass
{
    public static void useSomething()
    {
        JarBClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This compiles and you can create Jar A, however running it would throw an exception.

You can update your Jar B code:

```
public class JarBClass
{
    public static void doSomething()
    {
        System.out.println("all good");
    }
}
```

This compiles and you can re-create Jar B. Jar A can run without exception.

However if you update Jar B and change the API:

```
public class JarBClass
{
    public static void doSomething(String what)
    {
        System.out.println(what + " is all good");
    }
}
```

You will need to modify and recompile Jar A.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're correct: you'd simply re-create the JAR B that contained the new class and put it in the class path along with JARs A and C.